# Split a string by Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently thinking of how to split this kind of string into regex using c#.

```
[01,01,01][02,03,00][03,07,00][04,06,00][05,02,00][06,04,00][07,08,00][08,05,00]
```

Can someone knowledgeable on regex can point me on how to achieved this goal?

sample regex pattern that don't work:

```
[\dd,\dd,\dd]
```

sample output:

```
[01,01,01]
[02,03,00]
[03,07,00]
[04,06,00]
[05,02,00]
[06,04,00]
[07,08,00]
[08,05,00]
```

Comment: Why regex? Just split at `']'`

Comment: I'm thinking if there is a better way rather that splitting it in ']'?

Comment: [`\[\d\d,\d\d,\d\d\]` maybe](http://refiddle.com/refiddles/5a3a093475622d4a68030000)?

Comment: string.Split is better

Comment: @CinCout and @Backs When splitting at `]`, you loose the `]`. See [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xrNwUV).

Comment: @UweKeim obviously there's a catch, which is easily fixable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the job in C# `(\[.+?\])`, e.g.:

```
var s = @"[01,01,01][02,03,00][03,07,00][04,06,00][05,02,00][06,04,00][07,08,00][08,05,00]";
var reg = new Regex(@"(\[.+?\])");
var matches = reg.Matches(s);
foreach(Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{m.Value}");
}
```

**EDIT** This is how the expression `(\[.+?\])` works

1. first the outter parenthesis, `(` and `)`, means to capture whatever the inside pattern matched
2. then the escaped square brackets, `\[` and `\]`, is to match the `[` and `]` in the source string
3. finally the `.+?` means to match one or more characters, but as few times as possible, so that it won't match all the characters before the first `[` and the last `]`

Comment: can you explain the regex pattern? if so i can marked it as answer.

Comment: @iamcoder Please see the updated answer

Answer (score 3):

I know you stipulated `Regex`, however it's worth looking at `Split` again, if for only for academic purposes:

**Code**

```
var input = "[01,01,01][02,03,00][03,07,00][04,06,00][05,02,00][06,04,00][07,08,00][08,05,00]";

var output = input.Split(']',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     .Select(x  => x + "]") // the bracket back
                     .ToList();

foreach(var o in output) 
   Console.WriteLine(o);
```

**Output**

> ```
> [01,01,01]
> [02,03,00]
> [03,07,00]
> [04,06,00]
> [05,02,00]
> [06,04,00]
> [07,08,00]
> [08,05,00]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The Regex solution below is restricted to 3 values of only 2 digits seperated by comma. Inside the *foreach* loop you can access the matching value via `match.Value`.

Remember to include `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

```
var input = "[01,01,01][02,03,00][03,07,00][04,06,00][05,02,00][06,04,00][07,08,00][08,05,00]";
foreach(var match in Regex.Matches(input, @"(\[\d{2},\d{2},\d{2}\])+"))
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: great it can be also done by this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the answer i also got it working by using this code

```
string pattern = @"\[\d\d,\d\d,\d\d]";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(myResult);

Debug.WriteLine(matches.Count);

foreach (Match match in matches)
   Debug.WriteLine(match.Value);
```